# Написання термінів, частина яких записується англійською

Tags: іншомовні-слова

Підкажіть, будь ласка, як за новим правописом треба писати терміни, частина яких записується англійською. Приклади: "Email клієнт"/"Email-клієнт", "MAC адреса"/"MAC-адреса".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мені непросто зараз логічно обґрунтували, але…

**Немає підстав писати окремо, бо українська мова**, на відміну від англійської, здається, **не має [атрибутивних іменників](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)** (іменників, що виконують функцію прикметників). Наприклад, ми не кажемо / не пишемо «tennis ball» (де «tennis» — укр. «теніс» — іменник, що виконує роль прикметника, а «ball» — укр. «м'яч»; дослівно було б «теніс м'яч»), ми кажемо «теніс*ний* м'яч» (де «тенісний» — *справжній* прикметник) або ж намагаємось утворити якесь *складне слово* (щось типу «тенісом'яч» чи «теніс-м'яч»; ці приклади надумані, але вживаються, наприклад, «глибиномір», «фітнес-клуб»). Тобто у Вашому випадку вибір може бути лише між написанням разом та дефісним написанням (якщо Ви, звісно, не використовуватимете граматичні прикметники на зразок «імейловий клієнт», «поштовий клієнт»).

Правила вибору між написанням разом і через дефіс нетривіальні (вони, до речі, змінилися між 2015 і 2019 у бік частішого написання разом), але **у випадку, коли перша частина слова лишається іноземною мовою, я не можу уявити написання разом.  Тобто зостається лише варіант «email-клієнт», «MAC-адреса»**.

Формально під це можно спробувати підтягти:

- [§ 36.2.2.а](https://2019.pravopys.net/sections/36/) ([сторінка 38](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=38)):

  > Правопис слів разом, із дефісом, окремо. <…> Складні іменники. <…> З дефісом пишемо: складні іменники, утворені з двох самостійних іменників без сполучного голосного звука. <…> Другий іменник складного слова відмінюємо, якщо перший: <…> визначає певну прикмету чи особливість предмета, особи, явища, названих другим: бíзнес-план, бі́знес-проє́кт, блок-систéма, буй-ту́р, ди́зель-мото́р, до́пінг-контрóль, дур-зíлля, жар-пти́ця, інтерне́т-видáння, інтерне́т-пóслуга, ко́зир-ді́вка, компа́кт-диск, кре́кінг-проце́с, піа́р-áкція, піа́р-кампáнія, розрúв-трава́, фан-клýб, фі́тнес-клуб, чар-зі́лля…
- [§ 36.2.2.г](https://2019.pravopys.net/sections/36/) ([сторінка 38](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=38)):

  > Правопис слів разом, із дефісом, окремо. <…> Складні іменники. <…> З дефісом пишемо: складні іменники, утворені з двох самостійних іменників без сполучного голосного звука. <…> Другий іменник складного слова відмінюємо, якщо перший: <…> є невідмінюваним іменником іншомовного походження: сýші-бар, караóке-бар…
- а у випадку «MAC-адреси» (media access control address) ще й [§ 35.5.7](https://2019.pravopys.net/sections/35/) ([сторінка 36](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=36)):

  > Правопис слів разом, із дефісом, окремо. Загальні правила правопису складних слів. <…> Складні слова без сполучного голосного звука. <…> З дефісом пишемо: <…> ініціальну абревіатуру, написану великими або малими літерами, з будь-яким  словом: ВІЛ-інфéкція, ДНК-анáліз, ДНК-експерти́за, ВІП-зáла, е-декларувáння, е-декларáція…

На практиці у випадках, коли слово логічно мало б писатися разом (а не через дефіс), але воно являє собою поєднання іншомовної й української частин (тому його банально неестетично писати разом), іноді використовують апостроф: «email'ова адреса», «за'approve'ти запит» тощо. Але, по-перше, як ми бачили вище, Ваші випадки навіть суто логічно мають писатися через дефіс (бо цілком вписуються під відповідні правила), а по-друге, таке написання через апостроф ніде не регламентоване (тобто якщо його й можна десь використовувати, то лише в неформальному листуванні).

Comment: Дякую за відповідь!

Comment: @Олена, якщо Вас влаштовує відповідь, то Ви можете натиснути «✓», щоб позначити її прийнятою.

Comment: Зробила. Вибачайте, я новенька)

Comment: @Олена, дякую Вам!

Comment: У випадках на кшталт "заапрувити" краще все-таки писати все українською :)

Comment: @Kreiri, не знаю… З естетичної точки зору — так. Але з практичної: (1) може бути схожість зі справді українськими словами; (2) кириличну транслітерацію не завжди очевидно як «декодувати» назад в англійське слово (в англійській є майже офомони, плюс не завжди люди одним способом транслітерують).